# Why am I getting this segfault when using the Python/C API?

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, python-c-api

I am getting a segmentation fault when decrefing a `PyObject*` in my C++ code using the Python/C API, and I can't figure out why.  I am using C++ and Python 2.7.  I am using new-style classes for future Python 3 compatibility.

My goal is to create a C++ class `MyClass` to serve as a wrapper for a class defined in a Python module.  In the `MyClass` constructor, I pass in the name of the Python module, import the module, locate the class (which always has a pre-defined name `PyClass`), and call that class to create an instance of it.  I then store the resulting `PyObject*` in `MyClass` for future use.  In the `MyClass` destructor, I decref that stored `PyObject*` to avoid memory leaks.

I have already verified that everything is working correctly as far as locating the class and creating an instance of it.  I have even verified that I can use the stored `PyObject*` in other `MyClass` methods, for example, to access methods in the `PyClass`.  However, when the destructor does the decref, it causes a segfault.

Here is a sample of my code.  I also call `Py_Initialize()` and `Py_Finalize()` elsewhere at appropriate times, and I have left out some of my error-checking code for brevity:

`MyPythonModule.py`

```
class PyClass:
    pass
```

`MyClass.h`

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(const char* modulename);
    ~MyClass();
private:
    void* _StoredPtr;
};
```

`MyClass.cpp`

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(const char* modulename) {
    _StoredPtr = NULL;

    PyObject *pName = NULL, *pModule = NULL, *pAttr = NULL;

    // Import the Python module.
    pName = PyString_FromString(modulename);
    if (pName == NULL) {goto error;}
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    if (pModule == NULL) {goto error;}

    // Create a PyClass instance and store a pointer to it.
    pAttr = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "PyClass");
    if (pAttr == NULL) {goto error;}
    _StoredPtr = (void*) PyObject_CallObject(pAttr, NULL);
    Py_DECREF(pAttr);
    if (_StoredPtr == NULL) {goto error;}

error:
    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {PyErr_Print();}
    Py_XDECREF(pName);
    Py_XDECREF(pModule);
    return;
}

MyClass::~MyClass() {
    std::cout << "Starting destructor..."  << std::endl;
    Py_XDECREF((PyObject*)(_StoredPtr));
    std::cout << "Destructor complete."  << std::endl;
}
```

I know that I could avoid the segfault by leaving out the `Py_XDECREF()` in the destructor, but I am afraid of causing a memory leak because I do not understand exactly why this is happening.  It seems especially strange that I can use `_StoredPtr` successfully in other `MyClass` methods, yet I can't decref it.

I have also tried storing the `PyObject*` of the imported module in `MyClass` and holding on to it until after `_StoredPtr` is decrefed, but the `_StoredPtr` decref still segfaults.  I tried commenting out the `Py_DECREF(pAttr);` line, but that doesn't help.

As I mentioned, I can retrieve methods in the `PyClass` using `_StoredPtr`, and I have also tried storing these in `MyClass` and decrefing them in the destructor.  When I do this, I can decref `_StoredPtr`, but then it segfaults when I try to decref the method's `PyObject*`.  If I do this with several methods, it is always the last decref that causes the segfault, no matter what order I put them in.

Any insights as to what's happening here?

Comment: FWIW, the CPython source code uses `goto` quite a bit ... https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/listobject.c#l361

Comment: Your code uses reserved identifiers, which is for me reason enough not to look further. I'd also stop using C-style casts in C++. That said, use Boost.Python or a similar framework for writing Python modules in C++ instead of solving all problems that brings again.

Comment: CPython is C not C++, @mgilson! In C, you don't have objects with destructors, so you can't use RAII and similar idioms. Compare that to C++, where you can't skip across a constructor using `goto`, thus limiting the applicability of C++ RAII. I don't claim that `goto` is always bad in C++, using a smart pointer with custom deleter would be a good alternative.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt -- That's a fair point.  I haven't spent a lot of time with C++, but I did once use a C++ class that someone else wrote for tracking reference counts in Python...

Comment: @erip I am using the example in the Python docs https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/intro.html#exceptions

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What reserved identifiers are you talking about?  Also, Boost is not an option for me.

Comment: What kind of identifiers are reserved in C++? What has your research turned up?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Actually, I found the problem, and it had nothing to do with reserved identifiers or casting.By the way, if you found a reserved identifier in my code, it would have been much more helpful to just tell me what it was rather than sending me to do (more) research that turned out to be a complete waste of time.

Comment: I didn't really expect the abuse of reserved identifiers to break your code in this particular case. However, I don't see a reason to take a chance! It surely is a bug in your code and fixing it doesn't hurt. Actually, it moves your example closer to what you want when creating a minimal example!

Comment: Same problem here, segfault when `Py_XDECREF(pBa)`, after I successfully get `PyByteArrayObject * pBa`from `PyArg_ParseTuple`.

Comment: Turns out that either I decref the Py function return values, or members thereof. If I decref them both, I get a segfault at the next Py function call.

Comment: @CarrieD. Can you please share what the problem was and how you solved it? I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(const char* modulename) {
_StoredPtr = NULL;

PyObject *pName = NULL, *pModule = NULL, *pAttr = NULL;

// Import the Python module.
pName = PyString_FromString(modulename);
if (pName == NULL) {goto error;}
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
if (pModule == NULL) {goto error;}

// Create a PyClass instance and store a pointer to it.
pAttr = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "PyClass");
if (pAttr == NULL) {goto error;}
_StoredPtr = (void*) PyObject_CallObject(pAttr, NULL);
Py_DECREF(pAttr);
if (_StoredPtr == NULL) {goto error;}
else{
// do something with _StoredPtr
Py_XDECREF((*PyObject)_StoredPtr)
}
error:
    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {PyErr_Print();}
    Py_XDECREF(pName);
    Py_XDECREF(pModule);
    return;
}

MyClass::~MyClass() {}
```

I basically moved the XDECREF outside the destructor into the function that is using the PyObject.